# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Report>

Tags: reporting, list

I have read all the [related questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=Initial%20term%20of%20field%20expression%20must%20be%20a%20concrete%20SObject) here, but couldn't found the answer to my problem (since must of them were just trying to access a list with dot notation like if it was an sObject).

I'm just trying to run a report from apex like

```
//Update
private List<Report> reports;

private Set<Id> getContactIdsFromReport(Id reportId){
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();

    Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
    ...
    return ids;
}
```

And the third line is throwing that error at compile time, I have tried some variations that didn't work either. What am I missing?

Comment: The code you have posted compiles. Perhaps you have removed the line that causes the compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a variable called Reports in your class scope (a variable by the name of Reports, case-insensitive). This variable is shadowing the Reports object in the System namespace. You should rename the variable, or use the System namespace:

```
public List<Report> reports { get; set; }  // Rename me, or...
...
    Set<Id> getContactIdsFromReport(Id reportId) {
        Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
        System.Reports.ReportResults results = System.Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true); // Use System namespace here
        ...
        return Ids;
    }
}
```